# Using Scanner in Java how can I hasNext(aString) where the string is not regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to do as my question states, sooo I have the following code which would find the match.

`String test = scan.next();

if (test.equals("$let"))

 return 1;`

However, I would prefer to use hasNext as to not consume a token; however, when i do the following it fails.

`if (scan.hasNext("$let"))

 return 1;`

I realize the when giving has next a variable it expects a pattern, but I thought if i don't have any regex symbols it should work. I also thought $ was possibly some regex symbol so I tried /$ however, that did not work!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use \\$ to escape the regex, but it's easier to just get the next() and save the result.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have some arbitrary string that you want to match literally with no meanings to any regex metacharacters, you can use [`java.util.Pattern.quote`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("$)}**");
System.out.println(sc.hasNext(Pattern.quote("$)}**"))); // prints "true"
System.out.println(sc.hasNext("\\Q$)}**\\E")); // prints "true"
System.out.println(sc.hasNext("$)}**")); // throws PatternSyntaxException
```

You can also use the `\Q` and `\E` quotation markers, but of course you need to ensure that the quoted string must not itself contain `\E`.